# NativeScript Rounded Input?

Tags: html, css, nativescript

I'm trying to make an app using NativeScript and Angular and want my text input boxes to have rounded corners like this:

[image]

Currently, this is how it looks: [image]

Here's my html:

```html
<TextField style="margin-top: 20;" class="input-rounded" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" returnKeyType="next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
```

and then here's my .css:

```css
TextField {
  border-width: 1;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: white;
  height: 7%;
  width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 20;
}
```

I've also tried setting the border radius to 1rem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving `border-radius` in number only

```css
.input-rounded {
  margin-top: 20;
  border-width: 1;
  border-color: white;
  background-color: white;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius:10;
}
```

```html
<TextField class="input-rounded" hint="Email Address" keyboardType="email" returnKeyType="next" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
```

Edit: Modified the code. Removed the inline style tag and added css using class instead of element selector.